# BASH: how to define an array as environment variable before calling a bash script

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

In bash, you can do

```
MYVAR="somevalue" ./myscript.sh
```

and the variable MYVAR will be defined when running myscript.sh.

My questions is: can I do the same for arrays? Unfortunately, neither of the following works.

```
MYARR=( 1 2 ) ./myscript.sh
MYARR[0]=1 MYARR[1]=2 ./myscript.sh
declare -a MYARR=( 1 2 ) ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Just note that passing arrays through environment variables won't work because environment variables are always strings. Arrays don't fit there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Incredibility weird.... I have never seen that before.

It looks like the array is not passed to the subshell. One way around this is to source the script instead of executing it:

```
declare -a MYARR=( 1 2 ); . ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Nice, this works! Does sourcing have any drawbacks except for the fact that the shell is closed when myscript.sh calls exit?

Comment: Your shell will also retain any variables, functions, and mode settings etc left from the script. For example, if it does a `set -f`, filename wildcards won't work for you until you turn that option back off. You can avoid this (and the exit problem) by running it in a subshell by putting `( ... )` around the relevant section.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that, thanks. I was using xterm -e "..." so this is not an issue. Unfortunately, however, I cannot do xterm -e "MYARR=( 1 2 ); . ./myscript.sh || read -p \"Error: print [Enter] to continue.\"" anymore. And xterm does not return the exit value of the executed command.